# Unknown Dice Game

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

Does anyone know what this game is? My wife picked up 2 of these shakers and I cannot identify the game.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Are they all the tokens?  Only 8 numbered as show with the word 'nine'  or do others exist?

Comment: Looks like you're probably missing 3, 4, 5, six, 7, 8, 10,13 and possibly 17+. The only reason I can think of to write "nine" when the others are digits is to differentiate it from 6/six.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [Kelly Pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_pool), missing a few pieces (should have "peas" 1-16, per L. Scott Johnson's comment). Kelly pool's page doesn't mention a die, but you can probably just add the variant mentioned on the [Bottle Pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottle_pool) page.

Comment: I can see a bottle in that link but I cant find any reference to the numbered tokens.  What bits do you think are missing?

Comment: Fixed the answer, set it to bottle pool originally because it mentioned using a die, guess I just assumed it used the red bits.

Comment: Kelly pea balls come 16 to  a set, numbered 1,2,3,4,5,six,7,8,nine,10,11,12,13,14,15,16. cf: https://www.dkgameroomoutlet.com/deluxe-leather-tally-bottle-wooden-kelly-pea-ball-set

Comment: Kelly Pool looks to be the most accurate answer for this one. It is true, my 4 year old daughter did a pretty good job of losing most of the numbered tokens. I'm still wondering what the 6 sided die is used for though.

Comment: From bottle pool link: "One further variation places a 6-sided die (although other sided die could also be used) on top of the bottle. If the bottle is knocked over and the die knocked onto the table, the player is awarded points equal to whatever side of the die lies facing upward when the die comes to a stop. This adds a random effect to hitting the bottle and in practice often results in players only striking the bottle in combination with other point-scoring shots."